# AWS CQL editor showing incorrect data when queried

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cassandra, cql

I have inserted the order with all the necessary fields into Cassandra using python (cassandra-driver==3.21.0).
Table schema looks like this:

```
Columns datatype
-----------------------
name         text
phone        text
date         text
inserteddate text


Name = 'Bob'
Phone = '48562'
Date = '2023-02-24'
Inserteddate = '2023-02-15 05:30:00.0',
orderId = 'test'
Data = [Name,Phone,Date,Inserteddate,orderId]
query = "INSERT INTO  dev.orders (name,phone,date,inserteddate,orderid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
session.execute(query,Data)
```

After completing the insertion I am checking aws cql editor to check if it was inserted properly with below command.

```
SELECT * FROM dev.orders where date ='2023-02-24' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

It is fetching the record with which I have inserted but the date column is showing as null.

Expected result in console:
Results:

```
name   phone   date         inserteddate             orderid 
bob    48562   2023-02-24   2023-02-15 05:30:00.0    test
```

What I got from aws cql editor
Results:

```
name   phone   date         inserteddate             orderid 
bob    48562   null         2023-02-15 05:30:00.0    test
```

But when checked using putty to fetch the record, I could see the original value for the date field. What could be the reason for it showing incorrect data when using cql editor? How to overcome this?

Comment: Would you please update your question with (1) sample table schema, (2) sample data, and (3) sample output? This would help us troubleshoot your issue. Cheers!

Comment: @Erick Ramirez..I have updated.Could you help resolving it.Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but what is the PRIMARY KEY definition, and why are you using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive?

Comment: orderid is the primary key here..it requires data filtering that's why have used allow filtering

Comment: What is the ACTUAL table schema? 